# How to Combine two arrays into an object with keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a problem that I can't figure out. Basically I receive two arrays with coordinates in them:

```
const xData = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
const yData = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
```

I need to combine these two arrays into an object like so:

```
var data = [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 3, y: 4 }, { x: 5, y: 6 }, { x: 7, y: 8 }, { x: 9, y: 10 }];
```

I combined the two arrays to get the coordinates together

```js
const xData = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
const yData = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

var coords = xData.map((v, i) => { return [v, yData[i]]; });

console.log(coords);
```

I'm not sure how to take this new array and turn it into an object assigning `x` and `y` keys to each to element of the object.

Comment: `coords.map(([x, y]) => ({x, y}))`

Comment: or `var coords = xData.map((x, i) => ({ x, y:yData[i]}));` to do it in a single map function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First way is to map your intermediate array to an array of objects

```js
const xData = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
const yData = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

var coords = xData.map((v, i) => [v, yData[i]]).map(([x, y]) => ({x, y}));

console.log(coords);
```

as a bonus, see the shorthand for your current map callback

second (preferred, unless you also want the array version as well) way is to map directly to an object

```js
const xData = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
const yData = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];

var coords = xData.map((x, i) => ({ x, y:yData[i]}));

console.log(coords);
```

You may need to read up on [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const xData = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9];
const yData = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
 

var coords = xData.map((v, i) => { return [v, yData[i]]; }).map(([x, y]) => ({x, y}));
console.log(coords);
```